# Need to change value of table column, when INSERT/UPDATE is performed for the row in sql

Tags: sql, plsql, key

Team
I have a table On my I first insert the table from source file, `STATUS` should be `NEW`. Where `EMP_ID` is primary key

```
EMP_TBL
--------------  
STATUS EMP_ID
--------------
NEW     E1
NEW     E2
NEW     E3
NEW     E4
NEW     E5
```

For some use case I will use insert/update operation using DB adapter in OIC. When the primary key value is already exist in table, then the STATUS should be set to 'REPROCESS'. For e.g
when I insert E3, E4 along with some new records E6,E7 from my source file to DB the already exist records should become 'REPROCESS'. Hence the current insert should make EMP_TBL to ( E1,E2,E4,E5 are processed and please skip from logic for this context)

```
    EMP_TBL
    --------------  
    STATUS EMP_ID
    --------------
    REPROCESS E3
    REPROCESS E4
    NEW       E6
    NEW       E7
```

when we make INSERT PKey exception will be thrown. How to handle this, does it require any trigger in `TABLE` definition or any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use insert or updates. The insert will raise an exception because of the violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint - that cannot be fixed in a trigger. Instead check out the MERGE statement.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_tbl (
   emp_id VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY
   ,status VARCHAR2(10)
);

Table EMP_TBL created.
```

Run process first time. No rows yet so this will set status NEW for all rows:

```
MERGE INTO emp_tbl base
USING (
   SELECT 'E1' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E2' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E3' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E4' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E5' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
      ) source ON ( base.emp_id = source.emp_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET base.status = 'REPROCESS'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
   emp_id
   ,status )
VALUES
   ( source.emp_id
     ,'NEW' );

SELECT *
  FROM emp_tbl;

EMP_ID         STATUS    
-------------- ----------
E4             NEW       
E2             NEW       
E1             NEW       
E3             NEW       
E5             NEW
```

Now run process again with different values. Some already exist, some don't:

```
MERGE INTO emp_tbl base
USING (
   SELECT 'E3' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E4' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E6' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E7' AS emp_id
     FROM dual
      ) source ON ( base.emp_id = source.emp_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET base.status = 'REPROCESS'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
   emp_id
   ,status )
VALUES
   ( source.emp_id
     ,'NEW' );

4 rows merged.

SELECT *
  FROM emp_tbl;

EMP_ID         STATUS    
-------------- ----------
E1             NEW       
E2             NEW       
E3             REPROCESS 
E4             REPROCESS 
E5             NEW       
E7             NEW       
E6             NEW
```