# ORACLE MERGE WHEN 'USING' CONDITION HAVE NULL VALUES NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I need to make entry in target table but in 2 different secenarios

1. If already a record exists in target table need to update certain values
2. If no record exists I need to insert records

I have choosen "merge" to do that

```
MERGE INTO target tar
            USING (SELECT  DISTINCT A.col1,B.col1,A.col2
            FROM target A   JOIN src B 
            ON A.col1=B.col1 AND B.col2 =A.col2
            ) src
        ON (src.col1=tar.col1 and src.col2=tar.col2 )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET tar.col4 =37,
                           tar.col5=6,
                           tar.col6=SYSDATE,
                           tar.col7=123,
                           tar.col8=SYSDATE,
                           tar.col9=123
            WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN
                INSERT (tar.col1,tar.col2,tar.col3,tar.col4)
                values( src.col1,src.col2,37,6,);
```

The Problem the select query I am using in "Using" is fetching null result
my expectation is this is "NOT MATCHED" condition it should result insert records

but this is not merging
Will oracle Merge not work if null result is derived on "using" condtion?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047055/need-to-change-value-of-table-column-when-insert-update-is-performed-for-the-ro/78047379#78047379) answer of an example of merge. Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

> but this is not merging

It will not work when the query has syntax errors:

- ```sql
  SELECT  DISTINCT A.col1,B.col1,A.col2
  FROM target A   JOIN src B 
  ON A.col1=B.col1 AND B.col2 =A.col2
  ```

  Has two `col1` columns being selected. Since you test that `A.col1=B.col1` then you can remove the duplicate `col1` from the `SELECT` clause.

  However, you probably do not need to `JOIN` in the `USING` clause as you are already joining the tables in the `ON` clause.
- ```sql
  INSERT (tar.col1,tar.col2,tar.col3,tar.col4)
  values( src.col1,src.col2,37,6,)
  ```

  Has a spurious trailing comma.

You can simplify the query to:

```sql
MERGE INTO target tar
USING src
ON (src.col1 = tar.col1 AND src.col2 = tar.col2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET col4 = 37,
      col5 = 6,
      col6 = SYSDATE,
      col7 = 123,
      col8 = SYSDATE,
      col9 = 123
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (col1, col2, col3, col4)
  VALUES (src.col1, src.col2, 37, 6);
```